# Handle null pointer exception when oracle data default is null for data type number

Tags: java, oracle

I have the following table in Oracle database:
[image]

I have the entity class:

```
public class CollCmpCampaigns implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String campaignCode;
    private String campaignName;
    private Long showEventsDaysOut;
    private Long emailPreviewDaysPrior;
    private Long editAllowedDaysPrior;
    private Long warningDaysInCheckpoint;
    private Long eventDaysToPull;
    private Long uploadListDaysPrior;

   .... 
   //getters and setters
```

and I have the following method in a mapper class:

```
public com.***.catalogservices.generated.ws.CollCmpCampaigns mapCollCmpCampaignsToXML(CollCmpCampaigns ccc) {
        com.***.catalogservices.generated.ws.CollCmpCampaigns generatedCcc = new com.***.catalogservices.generated.ws.CollCmpCampaigns();

        generatedCcc.setCampaignCode(ccc.getCampaignCode());
        generatedCcc.setCampaignName(ccc.getCampaignName());
        generatedCcc.setShowEventsDaysOut(ccc.getShowEventsDaysOut());
        generatedCcc.setEmailPreviewDaysPrior(ccc.getEmailPreviewDaysPrior());
        generatedCcc.setEditAllowedDaysPrior(ccc.getEditAllowedDaysPrior());
        generatedCcc.setWarningDaysInCheckpoint(ccc.getWarningDaysInCheckpoint());
        generatedCcc.setEventDaysToPull(ccc.getEventDaysToPull());
        generatedCcc.setUploadListDaysPrior(ccc.getUploadListDaysPrior());
        return generatedCcc;
    }
```

When debugging, I am getting the following result set from the query:

```
CollCmpCampaigns[campaignCode=CMP1,
campaignName=Grad Event OnCampus_Full Campaign,
showEventsDaysOut=33,
emailPreviewDaysPrior=31,
editAllowedDaysPrior=24,
warningDaysInCheckpoint=33,
eventDaysToPull=0,
uploadListDaysPrior=<null>]
```

From the debug result, as you can see `uploadListDaysPrior` has the value `<null>`. (Obviously) Whenever I try to set the values when getter values are null, I am getting `java.lang.NullPointerException` exception. 
 
I can fix this issue by putting a condition like this:

```
if(ccc.getUploadListDaysPrior() != null){
    generatedCcc.setUploadListDaysPrior(ccc.getUploadListDaysPrior());
}
```

But is this really a good approach? 
Shall I ask the DBA to put the data_default value 0 in the table for Number type instead of null or shall I put the conditions like above for all?

Comment: Must the type be `Long`?  Can it be the primitive `long`?

Comment: Do you have any logic in `CollCmpCampaigns#setUploadListDaysPrior(Long)`? Generally you can assign `null` values to wrapper types. Is it invalid

Comment: @AndrewS I generally use Long. 

@AlehMaksimovich No logic there actually: 
`public void setUploadListDaysPrior(Long uploadListDaysPrior) {
  this.uploadListDaysPrior = uploadListDaysPrior;
 }`

Comment: Why use `Long`?  Unless there is a meaningful difference between null and 0.

Comment: @AlehMaksimovich @AndrewS : Never realized my JAXB generated class had `long` type instead of `Long`. Modified my xsd file (which I never mentioned on my question, sorry about that...) and it worked! Thank you very much...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never realized my JAXB generated class has `long` type instead of `Long`. Modified my xsd file (which I never mentioned on my question) to:

```
<xs:complexType name="CollCmpCampaigns">
    <xs:sequence  minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element name="campaignCode" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="campaignName" type="xs:string" />
        <xs:element name="showEventsDaysOut" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:element name="emailPreviewDaysPrior" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:element name="editAllowedDaysPrior" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:element name="warningDaysInCheckpoint" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:element name="eventDaysToPull" type="xs:long" />
        <xs:element name="uploadListDaysPrior" type="xs:long" />
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="GetCollCmpCampaignsResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="Response">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="CollCmpCampaigns" type="CollCmpCampaigns" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Then I regenerated the class and It worked!